How to "show children" from PageListingViewSet
When creating a Wagtail 6 PageListingViewSet, we are able to add child pages via an action under the ellipsis menu:

That will, in turn, cause an icon to appear next to the title of the page that has children:

However, clicking the title with the icon only takes the user to the edit page for that particular page.
How can the user navigate to a listing of the children of that page when viewing the PageListingViewSet?
class MagazineIssueViewSet(PageListingViewSet):
    model = MagazineIssue
    menu_label = "Issues"
    icon = "doc-full-inverse"
    add_to_admin_menu = True
    search_fields = ("title",)
    filterset_class = MagazineIssueFilterSet


magazine_issue_viewset = MagazineIssueViewSet("magazine_issues")


I've added a related feature request: https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/issues/11974

On further browsing the Wagtail source code, I found the NavigateToChildrenColumn component which, at the time of opening the question and currently, isn't documented.

